# What is the object to be attained according to Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

There are many processes described like bhakti, karma, jnana etc.. What is the object to be attained by these processes? Or What is the goal?

Comment: Know the Paramatma, realize the paramatma and go back to him!

Comment: Krishna Himself!

Comment: "Nanyah Pantha Vidyate Ayanaya"

Comment: i think thats clear from the last sloka of Gita: Sree, Vijaya, Bhuti, Dhruva Neeti and above all Yogeshwara Krishna Himself.

Answer (score 2):

Gita starts with 'dharma' and ends with 'mama'. 
Take those togethter mama dharma.

Which means 'my dharmna'

The goal of gita is to do your dharma. if you are student, study nicely. if you are in army, fight nicely. After hearing gita, arjuna the warrior fought nicely.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

After giving the Gita-Upadesha to Arjuna, Sri Krishna asks him (18/72)

> O Partha, has this been listened to by you with a one-pointed mind? O Dhananjaya, has your delusion caused by ignorance been destroyed?

So He mentions the objective to be attained by studying Gita: Its the destruction of the delusion caused by ignorance.

When the delusion goes away completely, what is gained is mentioned in the end sloka (18/78) by Sanjaya:

> Where there is Krsna, the Lord of yogas, and where there is Partha, the wielder of the bow, there are fortune, victory, prosperity and unfailing prudence. Such is my conviction.

So these two slokas make the answer to the question clear.